# Hibernate IllegalArgumentException calling setter

Tags: java, sql, xml, hibernate, orm

I think I've got my [mapping issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7328060/hibernate-one-to-many-could-not-initialise-collection) solved, though now I'm running into a new error. When I try to run my test method, I now am presented with "PropertyAccessException: IllegalArgumentException occurred while calling setter of PageComment.userMadeTo". I'm not sure what could be causing this, I believe the getters and setters in my code are fine, so perhaps it is a problem with the mapping still?

HBM For User:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" 
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="User" table="user">
    <id name="username" column="Username" type="string">
        <generator class="assigned"></generator>
    </id>
    <property name="password" column="Password" type="string"></property>
    <property name="firstname" column="Firstname" type="string"></property>
    <property name="surname" column="Surname" type="string"></property>
    <property name="email" column="Email" type="string"></property>
    <property name="admin" column="Admin" type="integer"></property>

    <set name="commentsMadeTo">
        <key column="UserMadeTo"/>
        <one-to-many class="PageComment"/>
    </set>
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

HBM For PageComment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" 
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="PageComment" table="PageComment">
    <composite-id>
        <key-property name="userMadeBy" column="UserMadeBy" type="string" />
        <key-property name="time" column="Time" type="integer" />
        <generator class="assigned"></generator>
    </composite-id>
    <property name="commentText" column="CommentText" type="string"></property>
    <many-to-one name="userMadeTo" class="User" column="UserMadeTo" />
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Getter/Setter for the userMadeTo Attribute:

```
public void setUserMadeBy(String aUsername)
{
    userMadeBy = aUsername;
}

public String getUserMadeTo()
{
    return userMadeTo;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  <many-to-one name="userMadeTo" class="User" column="UserMadeTo" />
```

From your mapping , `userMadeTo` in the`PageComment` should return the `User` class instead of the String.  So , the setter and getter should be:

```
public class PageComment{

    private User user;

    public void setUserMadeBy(User aUser)
    {
        this.user = aUser;
    }

    public User getUserMadeTo()
    {
        return this.user;
    }
}
```